# Vba Excel. Cannot display help file to user-defined function in addin

Tags: user-defined-functions, chm, excel-addins

After I saved an xlsm file as an xlam file (an addin) and installed the addin. The help file can be displayed by clicking on the "Help on this function" in Insert Function dialog box.
 However, after I closed Excel and opened again. The addin was still installed, but the help file cannnot be displayed. To get it displayed, I need to uninstall and re-install the addin again while Excel was still opened OR uninstall the addin, close the Excel, and install the addin again.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_AddinInstall()
```

`Installed = True`
 `Application.MacroOptions "AvgN", HelpFile:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\AvgN Help.chm"`

```
End Sub
```

How to get the help file displayed without needing to uninstall and re-install the addin again and again? Thank you.

Comment: Which MS Office Version (2007, 2010 or 2013) you are using?

Comment: I tried it on both 2010 and 2013. Thanks.